# Marker file generated by the precompilation tool

Tags: mono

Greetings,

I am deploying my website on an webserver with mono

I am choosing the publish option but when I try to access any aspx page this appears

```
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!
```

I read something about the virtual path and since I deploying on http://www.mydomain.com/tests/gata/ I used the virtual path with the value /tests/gata... but still no use... I always have the same result...

Can anyone explain me why???

Answer (score 0):

Precompilation support for ASP.NET sites is only available in Mono 2.4 and later.  What version of Mono are you running?

That virtual path looks like it should be the correct option; however, I would consider trying a few things:
1) If you are depending on [AutoConfiguration](http://www.mono-project.com/AutoHosting) to handle your Apache configuration, you may want to consider explicitly configuring Apache.  You can use the [Apache mod_mono configuration tool hosted on the mono website](http://www.go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/).
2) Similarly, depending on what you have hosted in /tests, you may want to consider trying to deploy your application to an application path that isn't so deeply nested - perhaps just deploy to the /gata virtual path.  (I just wonder if something is causing mod_mono / Apache to not recognize that /tests/gata is the root of an ASP.NET application.)

Answer (score 0):

Set your website as updateable.

Open your solutin file in the text editor and check if Updateable property is set to true

```
AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
```

OR

Check your aspnet_compiler.exe parameters. You should use it with -u option.